# I have the following error "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;" when I click on my webPart

Tags: 2013, web-part, error, web-part-gallery

I have add a Web Part to my sharepoint 2013 site but I click on it in the Web Part Gallery,  the site page return the following error

> "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;".

Can someone explain that and give me a solution?

Comment: is it custom webpart? did you copied from other site /webapp?

Comment: It's Web Part which I have achieved on visual studio 2013 and I have uploaded the file (Web Part file) in The Web Part Gallery.

Comment: so you did not deploy as a solution?

Comment: I have deploy the solution but I didn't see the utility to do that because visual studio return the deploy was a succeed but nothing happen on the sharepoint site.

Comment: You can use powershell to deploy the solution in sharepoint...use add-spsolution to add it farm then install-spsolution to deploy it.

Comment: And after I have done that, I have uploaded the file (Web Part file) in The Web Part Gallery.

Comment: if it is solution, then you have to deploy it becuase that required backend stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the custom webpart which you uploaded into the Site collections's web part gallery. I think you need to deploy and install that solution in order to use it.

- You need to add solution 1st [Add-SPSolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607552.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- After that you need to install it.[Install-SPSolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx)
- Sometime you need to enable it at site collection, depends upon the scope.
  [Enable-SPFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx)

Also check this post: [Has anyone seen this error; $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42001/has-anyone-seen-this-error-resourcescore-importerrormessage)

Comment: I test your solution but my Power Shell console don't recognize the cmdlets. Maybe, you have do something for these cmdlets work and I haven't done it.

Answer (score 0):

When I created my SharePoint Project I did not select farm solution so i got the same Error Message when I tried to **Add** my WebPart to the Site.

to change it to farm solution change the project propertys:

Sandboxed Solution from **true** to **false**

Include Assembly In Package from **false** to **true**

Maybe this can help.

Did you add your Webpart an then got the Error Message or while you try to add it to the site?

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70691/getting-the-error-resourcescore-importerrormessage-in-share-point-2013/210463#210463). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!